# C++ User inputs 4 numbers and the program check them which are greater which are less than

Tags: c++

I just want a quick hint how to do this to get me on track. By the way, I am new to programming, so some explanations would be well appreciated.

So it is basically like this: User inputs 4 numbers separated by space and the program puts in signs which numbers are greater between them which are less than.

For example:

```
input 1:
2 4 6 6
output 1:
2<4<6=6

input 2:
5 5 1 5
output 2:
5=5>1<5
```

Comment: Well how would you do it if you had to do it by hand?

Comment: Don't think about code. If someone were *saying* numbers to you, one at a time, and you had to perform this task on a paper with a pencil, how would you do it? Not surprisingly, the code to accomplish this will be near-identical to your answer to that question.

Comment: Hint: you only need to keep track of two numbers at a time in your program: the most recent, and the second most recent.

Comment: Are you having issues with the input of the numbers?  Or the use of `if` statements?  More details would be appreciated.

Comment: @WhozCraig Well, first of all, I'd wait to hear for the first two numbers and then put the sign between, then wait for another number and put a sign between them and so on. Something like that?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have no idea where to start to be honest, what to use.

Comment: @DovydasRamašauskas yup, that's pretty-much exactly how most anyone would do it.

Comment: Oh, so you check two numbers using if statement after that check another numbers and so on?

Comment: They key trick is to copy the present number to the previous number *before* reading the next number.

Comment: This is a Q&A, not a hint generator!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// create variables to store the numbers
int first, second;

// read in the first numbers
cin >> first;
// output the first number
cout << first;

// loop through the numbers as they are inputed
while(cin >> second) {
  // check all the possibilities 
  if(first < second) cout << "<";
  else if(first > second) cout << ">";
  else cout << "=";
  cout << second;
  first = second;
  // go back around again
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's totally different way that I was thinking. I was thinking doing this using if statements, but this is pretty cool. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @DovydasRamašauskas: Gary _is_ doing it using `if` statements.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah, I see it, but I did it using 3 ifs. Thanks anyways!